# show product discount on order email template

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, order-email

I would like to show product discount percentage on email template. i am using this code but its showing discount on product details page not on order email.

```
<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
        <p class="special-price yoursaving">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Your Saving:') ?></span>
            <span class="price">
                <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Display Discount percent end ?>
```

Comment: This code should be in your question, not in an ephemeral comment. Use the [edit] link to edit your question.

Comment: i am adding this code on App/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml but its not working

Comment: @grgarside <?php 
$originalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
$percentage = 0;
if ($originalPrice > $finalPrice) {
    $percentage = round(($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice);
}
if ($percentage) {
    echo $this->__('%s', $percentage . '%'. 'Off');
}
?>